# Get value of input in react native

Tags: react-native

Is there any way to get input value without use `onChangeText`?

I think it's not so good for simple work for example when I want to only when press login button get username and password from inputs.

In react js I use `this.input = React.createRef()` then assign ref to the component and when button press get value with `this.input.current.value` but value is undefined in react native

I try `this.input._lastNativeText` or `this.input._lastNativeValue` but they also undefined

Answer (score 0):

i've tried this code on ios and it works!

```
const Test = () => {
  const thisIp = useRef()
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{
      flex: 1
    }}>
      <TextInput
      style={{
        borderWidth: 1
      }}
        ref={ref => thisIp.current = ref}
      />
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
        console.log(thisIp.current._lastNativeText)
      }}>
        <Text>Get</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </SafeAreaView>
  )
}
```

Here is the result when i run code, type sth to input then click button **Get**
[image]